# Looping multiple hashtags in php string to insert into database

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am building a system and wish to allow people to leave comments with hash tags in them, for example "This is an #example #of #what I wish to achieve".

I have managed thus far to be able to insert the first word if multiple words are hash tagged, see below:

```
happysam | #new #more #insert | #new

happysam | #new #more #insert | new
```

The code I have written to achieve this is:

```
preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/',$message,$matches);
$len = count($matches);
if($len > 0)
{
foreach($matches as $match)
    {
        $i = 0;
        $ins = "INSERT INTO teamHash (user, message, hashtag,time) VALUES ('$user', '$message', '$match[$i]','$time')";
        $query = $conn->prepare($ins);
        $query->execute();
    }
}
```

What would be the best approach to modify my code so that I can loop over each hash tagged word and then insert in the text, i.e. "example" rather than "#example"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_match_all` returns a multi-dimensional array on successful match. Here,`$matches[0]` is an array of full pattern matches and`$matches[1]` is an array of strings matched by the first parenthesized subpattern. You should loop through `$matches[1]` instead:

```
foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value.' ';
    # code for inserting into database...
}
```

Output

```
new more insert example new more insert
```

Comment: To elaborate, in most regex engines, match group "0" is the entire string that matched, which you want is the contents of the first capture group (capture groups are parts of the regex pattern wrapped in parens), which is at index "1".

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't need regex:

```
$matches = array_map('trim', explode('#', $message));
```

Comment: This won't work as there are pipe characters (`|`) in between. [Demo](https://eval.in/105208)

Comment: I took those for imaginary db column delimiters.